# Rails make public,tmp and log folders outside the Root Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everytime that the carrierwave save a file, go to app/public folder, and the tmp and log folder get bigger overtime, so, is possible to make these folder outside the RailsApp?

change the `Rails.root.join("")` on the application.rb is the only way to do it?

on mina deploy is possible to create shared_path if created ouside have to symlink the path?

Comment: can you put these in gitignore so they're not pushed?

Comment: @maxple I guess, you meant `.gitignore`. Observe **dot** :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying on a *nix box then symlinks are the way to go.  I haven't used Mina, but if you deploy with Capistrano then you can script re-creation of whatever symlinks are needed fairly easily.

Just looking at the Mina page, you should be able to write a task to re-create your symlinks on deploy:
[writing_your_own_tasks](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/master/docs/writing_your_own_tasks.md)